# R/GGPLOT one Choropleth Map from each column in a Data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth

I have a data frame containing 48 hourly observations from each state. State names are in column 1 and columns 2:49 contain the observations for each hour. Each column is being used to generate a Choropleth map of the US for that hour. I have been able to generate a single map with the code as follows where the data frame is named "qso_per_hour".

```
map_hours<-colnames(qso_per_hour[2:49]) #drop state column, get just hour column names
this_map<-map_hours[18]  # hour 18 as an example
#
ggplot(qso_per_hour, aes_string(map_id="states", fill=this_map))+
    geom_map(map=states_map, colour="black") # other formatting code trimmed
```

What I want to do then is generate all 48 hourly maps, each on its own page, and save them off to a graphics file. As a start I am just trying to get them displayed on screen. When I put this code into a simple for loop it no longer draws the map.

```
map_hours<-colnames(qso_per_hour[2:49]) #drop state column, get just hour column names
for (this_map in map_hours) {
ggplot(qso_per_hour, aes_string(map_id="states", fill=this_map))+
    geom_map(map=states_map, colour="black") # other formatting code trimmed
}
```

When run, an R Graphic:Device window opens but the map is no longer drawn. The window remains gray. I have spent hours searching for an answer to this. It must be something simple. Anyone have any ideas? In debugging I have also put a readline statement at the end of the loop to make it wait for me to say it is ok to go to draw the next map, but that does not solve the issue.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: As a side note: To get help, it's always a good idea to provide a reproducible example so that readers can copy the code into R, run it and reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and I will do that in the future. I finally found the answer to my problem by searching for "ggplot does not work in a for loop". The trick is to make sure to explicitly print your resulting ggplot object which has been asked and answered many times before. I just didn't what question to ask.

Comment: @Scott You could answer your own question in order for other having the same problem to be able to use it. If it has been answered under a different form you can link the answer.

Comment: Ahh -- will do. I am not exactly fluent on this site yet.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation I discovered the problem I was having was an instance of "ggplot does not work in a for loop" which has been addressed several times before. Sorry I don't have the links. The solution is to put the ggplot function within a print() function. Then it works just fine while included in a for loop.